# hide file extension in url in a server code wrote in nodejs

Tags: html, node.js

help me please, I just started learning noode.js but I don't know how to hide extension in a URL when accessing from localhost for which(webserver) I've written code in node.js

```
        var http = require('http');
        var fs = require('fs');
        const port = 5050
        var url = require('url');

        const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
var filename = "." + q.pathname;
console.log(q);
fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    return res.end("404 Not Found");
  } 
  else if(filename == './getmoved.html') 
  {
    res.writeHead(301, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
  }
  else
  {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(data);
  }
  return res.end();
});
   }).listen(5050);
```

when I open a URL in a web browser as http://localhost:5050/index ,it should open index.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you better use a webserver for node, like Express.js. But for educational purposes, I would try something like the following.

Create a folder called `public` next to your `server.js` file and add the following three files:

1. 404.html
2. index.html
3. otherpage.html

**404.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>404</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Oops! Page not found...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the index page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**otherpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The other page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the node web server, server.js:

```
const util = require('util');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// Promisify some functions so async/await syntax can be used
const fsReaddir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
const fsReadFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

const port = 5050

// Define a folder to store the html files
const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

const server = http.createServer(async function (req, res) {

  // Read the filenames in your public folder
  const allFiles = await fsReaddir(publicDir);

  // Optionally filter out any files with another extension than html
  const htmlFiles = allFiles.filter(fileName => /\.html$/.test(fileName))

  // Parse the requested url
  const q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  console.log('Requested: ' + q.pathname);

  // If no path is given, default to index.html
  if(q.pathname === '/') {
    console.log('Falling back to index')
    const data = await fsReadFile(path.join(publicDir, 'index.html'));
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data.toString());
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  // Loop through all html files
  for(const htmlFile of htmlFiles) {
    const requestedPath = path.join(publicDir, q.pathname) + '.html';
    const actualPath = path.join(publicDir, htmlFile);

    // Check for a matching file
    if(requestedPath === actualPath) {
      console.log('Found match :-)');
      // It did match, so read the data of the file and respond
      const data = await fsReadFile(requestedPath);
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.write(data.toString());
      res.end();
      return;
    }
  }

  console.log('Page not found...');
  // No mathces were found, so respond with 404
  const data = await fsReadFile(path.join(publicDir, '404.html'));
  res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(data);
  res.end();

}).listen(port);
```